# How do I define a generic/templated class like the C# example below

Tags: c#, c++, templates

In C#:

```
public sealed class StateMachine<TState, TTrigger>
```

I'd like to write a C++ equivalent.

Comment: You're going to want to reword that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
template <typename TState, typename TTrigger>
class StateMachine
{
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) has a pretty good explanation of how to make template classes. Example:

```
// function template
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T GetMax (T a, T b) {
  T result;
  result = (a>b)? a : b;
  return (result);
}

int main () {
  int i=5, j=6, k;
  long l=10, m=5, n;
  k=GetMax<int>(i,j);
  n=GetMax<long>(l,m);
  cout << k << endl;
  cout << n << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Use this in combination with [this previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712992/how-to-define-sealed-class-in-c) to achieve the sealed aspect of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use what Stuart and Xeo proposed, and if you want to make the class sealed here is [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/12600/) that explains how to do it.

EDITED: [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4444/A-non-inheritable-class) is even better.